# Crear un programa al que se le ingresen N numeros que seran guardados en un arreglo y determinar cuantos son pares y cuantes primos

Tags: array, bucle-for, java-util-scanner

Busco hacer un programa que de un arreglo de tamaño n que sea llenado por el usuario determine con base en los valores introducidos cuantos son pares y cuantos son primos.
El código es capaz de determinar por separado cada uno, es decir si se introducen únicamente números primos puede determinar cuantos son primos, pero si se introducen números pares toma a estos como primos, alguna sugerencia sobre que podría estar provocando este problema?

```
package com.mycompany.n_arreglos;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.util.Scanner;
/**
 *
 * @author Ismael
 */

public class matriz {
public static void main(String[]args)  {  
    //declaracion del scanner.
        Scanner leer=new Scanner(System.in);
        //declaracion,inicializacion y llenado del arreglo.
        int numeroDeElementos;
        numeroDeElementos=Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese el numero de espacios deseado."));
int []almacen= new int[numeroDeElementos];
        int pares=0;//contador de pares
//codigo que encuentra al numero que mas se repite        
        for(int i=0;i<numeroDeElementos;i++){
                    System.out.println("introduzca el elemento del espacio "+(i+1)+":");
                    almacen[i]=leer.nextInt();
                        //codigo que detecta la cantidad de numeros pares y primos
                         if(almacen[i] %2==0){
            pares++;
        }
        }
        //codigo que determina la cantidad de numeros primos(el error esta aqui, el codigo de arriba no tiene nada que ver)
        int i,cont=0;
for(i=0;i<numeroDeElementos;i++){
int div=0;
    for(int j=1;j<almacen[i];j++){
        
        if(almacen[i]%j==0){
            
           div++;
        }
    }
    if(div==2);{
    cont++;
}
}
      
       
                                     System.out.println("de los numeros que se ingresaron "+pares+" son pares,"+cont+" son primos.");
                                
                
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Este es un error

```
if(div==2);{
```

Y previamente debe extender el ciclo una entrada más:

```
for(int j=1; j <= almacen[i];j++)
```

Un par de sugerencias:

1. Unifique los formatos de salida: System.out o JOptionPane (de preferencia el primero yá que la aplicación no es gráfica).
2. Por estándar los nombres de las clases deben iniciar con mayúscula.
3. Evite las declaraciones en línea de las variables: int i,cont=0; (no hay una razón para no declarar i en la cabecera del ciclo)
4. Trate de separar las tareas empleando métodos: facilita la detección de errores y los problemas se vuelven increiblemente más simples de seguir y de entender (el código debe ser autoexplicativo -evite los comentarios-).